# Matching people from 2 groups based on highest number of similarities in three categories

Tags: r, matching

This is my first question on stack overflow so bear with me.

I'm hoping to match people from group 1 to group 2 based on the highest number of similarities across three categories ("Subjects", "Sectors", and "Geography"). I've provided an example of what I'm looking for below:

```
group   Name       Subjects                            Sectors  Geography  
1       Hannah     Science, Fisheries, Policy          F, S     North
1       Zach       Policy, Energy, Marine              S, N     South   
2       Chelsea    Energy, Marine, Fisheries           S, N     South
2       Titus      Science, Fisheries, Communication   F, S, N  West

#Matches
Hannah:Titus
Zach:Chelsea
```

I've scoured the internet for any examples of how to perform this type of matching using R without success. The closest I found was a dating algorithm (https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/matching/DatingAlgorithm) but it has limitations that prevent me from editing their example data. I have some but not much experience in R so any recommendations (especially basic ones) would be appreciated. Happy to elaborate if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The r find.matches function looks like it could be used to help solve for this type problem:
"Compares each row in x against all the rows in y, finding rows in y with all columns within a tolerance of the values a given row of x"

The documentation for the function includes this code sample...
(for your purposes, you'll be specifying your text values for x and y - not numeric values)

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.4-1/topics/find.matches

```
y <- rbind(c(.1, .2),c(.11, .22), c(.3, .4), c(.31, .41), c(.32, 5))
x <- rbind(c(.09,.21), c(.29,.39))
y
x
w <- find.matches(x, y, maxmatch=5, tol=c(.05,.05))


set.seed(111)       # so can replicate results
x <- matrix(runif(500), ncol=2)
y <- matrix(runif(2000), ncol=2)
w <- find.matches(x, y, maxmatch=5, tol=c(.02,.03))
w$matches[1:5,]
w$distance[1:5,]
# Find first x with 3 or more y-matches
num.match <- apply(w$matches, 1, function(x)sum(x > 0))
j <- ((1:length(num.match))[num.match > 2])[1]
x[j,]
y[w$matches[j,],]
```

For a more robust treatment of matching capabilities - you may wish to explore optmatch and RITools -

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optmatch/index.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RItools/index.html

which this paper discusses

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optmatch/vignettes/fullmatch-vignette.pdf

Additionally, you may find Jasjeet S. Sekhon's papers of interest (Multivariate and Propensity Score Matching Software for Causal Inference) - using his R Matching package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf

http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/MatchingJSS.pdf

http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/Match.html

http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient solution, it will probably not work if the number of entries becomes big.

I create a function that counts the number of matches in the 3 columns of interest. Then I generate all possible pairs and compute the pairwise distance.

```r
library(purrr)

distance <- function(x, y){
  dist_subjects <- length(intersect(x$lSubjects[[1]], y$lSubjects[[1]]))
  dist_sectors <- length(intersect(x$lSectors[[1]], y$lSectors[[1]]))
  dist_geography <- sum(x$Geography == y$Geography)
  sum(dist_subjects, dist_sectors, dist_geography)
}

psort <- function(a, b){
  # parallel sort each pair from 2 vectors and paste them together in order
  out <- ifelse(a < b, paste0(a,":",b), paste0(b,":",a))
  out
}


# format as list for convenience
df$lSubjects <- strsplit(df$Subjects, ", ")
df$lSectors <- strsplit(df$Sectors, ", ")



all_pairs <- expand.grid(first = transpose(df),
            second = transpose(df))

# filter out the pairs of someone with themselves
all_pairs <- all_pairs[!map2_lgl(all_pairs$first, all_pairs$second,
                                 ~ .x$Name == .y$Name),]
# filter out duplicate pairs (same names in different order)
all_pairs$pair_name <- map2_chr(all_pairs$first, all_pairs$second, ~psort(.x$Name,.y$Name))
all_pairs <- all_pairs[! duplicated(all_pairs$pair_name), ]

setNames(map2_int(all_pairs$first, all_pairs$second, distance),
          all_pairs$pair_name)
#>    Hannah:Zach Chelsea:Hannah   Hannah:Titus   Chelsea:Zach     Titus:Zach 
#>              0              0              2              2              0 
#>  Chelsea:Titus 
#>              0
```